# XSLT merging nodes based on differences

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Input XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <book name="akhil" root="indian" default_attribute="10">
        <type default_attribute="20">novel</type>
        <price>200</price>      
    </book>
    <book name="indian" default_attribute="0">
        <type default_attribute="0">novel</type>
        <price default_attribute="0">100</price>
        <category default_attribute="0">thriller</category>
    </book>
</root>
```

Required output :

```
<root>
    <book name="akhil" default_attribute="10">
        <type default_attribute="20">novel</type>
        <price default_attribute="0">200</price>
        <category default_attribute="0">thriller</category>
    </book> 
</root>
```

Using XSLT 1.0 how can we produce this output ?
Any help is appreciated .

The merge should take place in such a way that, if there is a root attribute, fetch book name with root attribute value, and then merge the original book ( with root attribute ) with the one without root attribute

If no book name exists with a given root attribute value, just need to output the current book node

Comment: You would have to give more explanation than this. What's the logic behind merging, on what fields is the merging being considered. Also, you've not posted the XSLT you've tried.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS I Have updated the question with relevant details , i don't have any prior experience with xslt, but i know this can be done using xsl

Comment: And what's to be done with the element `price` in the element with `root` attribute? What should happen to `book` elements if there are none other `book` elements with matching `root` attribute? Why has the `category`'s value changed to "thriller"? What if there are many book elements which match a `root` attribute?

Comment: Update the question, sorry for mistake

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using keys in XSLT to refer to `book` elements with their attributes. It may not do what you need, but I hope will help you solve your problem with little modifications as required:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="book-by-name" match="book" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:key name="book-by-root" match="book" use="@root"/>

    <!-- Identity transform template to copy nodes and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template to merge book with @name with match @root's book -->
    <xsl:template match="book[@root]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('book-by-name', @root)/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to merge @price with value from book[@root]/price -->
    <xsl:template match="book[not(@root) and count(key('book-by-root', @name)) > 0]/price">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('book-by-root', ../@name)/price"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book/@root"/>

    <xsl:template match="book[not(@root) and count(key('book-by-root', @name)) > 0]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can't we use exslt:set:intersection ?

Comment: Hi @AkhilThayyil, may be. I've not ever used the **extension function**.